# S3 resource Acces forbidden after upload with Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am using Laravel 9 and uploading files on S3.

I have created my bucket on S3.

I am doing this to upload the file:

```
$path = Storage::disk('s3')->put("/{$school->s3_container}/users", new File('resizedFile'));
```

I see the file in my bucket. But when I try to access to it via my browser, I have a 403.

I have declared "public" the access on this bucket.

So where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

In S3 services:

- disable the option 'Block all the public access'

In Laravel, filesystems.php, add some parameters in the definition of your disk :

- `'throw' => true,`  This help me to find the error
- `'visibility' => 'public'`

So my disk looks like this:

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => true,
            'visibility' => 'public'
        ],
```

Comment: you could simply pass ``'public'`` as the third parameter to the ``put`` method while storing the file. Without it, by default, its' private :)